# RestFB: How to get page likes?

Tags: restfb

I'm trying to retrieve the number of likes a facebook page has. 
Here's my code:

```
FacebookClient fb= new DefaultFacebookClient(tok, appSecret);
    Page page = fb.fetchObject("178697151159", Page.class, Parameter.with("likes", "true"));
    System.out.println("My pages likes: " + page.getLikes());
```

but, its giving null as output. 
I'm new to restFB. So please help me in getting this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.VERSION_2_6);
Page page = client.fetchObject("178697151159", Page.class, Parameter.with("fields","fan_count"));
System.out.println("My page likes: " + page.getFanCount());
```

You have to tell Facebook which fields (`fan_count`) you need and you should use the newest API (`2.6`).

Then the rest is very easy :)

Comment: Thank you, Norbert. I got it.

Comment: Nobert, how do i get the id of the users who liked a facebook page.
For e.g. something like:

Connection<Likes> myFeed = facebookClient23.fetchConnection(id + "/likes", Likes.class, Parameter.with("fields", "data.limit(0)"));

Comment: Norbert, 
when i use this code
Connection<Likes> myFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection(id + "/likes", Likes.class, Parameter.with("fields", "data.limit(0)"))

or

Likes likesData = facebookClient.fetchObject(id + "/likes", Likes.class, Parameter.with("fields", "data.limit(0)"));

I get only 23 likes data...but there are more than 50000 likes on this page. can you tell me the correct way to get ALL the LIKES

Comment: Its looks like when we get the pageId/likes query we get the pages that have been liked by the current page. What i need is user ids of all users that Like a Current Page. Can I get userIds of all users that have liked a Facebook Page ? how to do this using restfb?

Comment: First of all, the `data.limit(0)` makes no sense for me. Despite from that, you have to get the `fan_count` to get the count of likes. I don't think there is a way to fetch the list of users who liked the page. With 50000 likes you would reach a request limit very soon, anyway.

Comment: When i use the following query https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1347629308665541/feed?limit=100&access_token=146055952628403%7CZLntKASz1sjS1y8ZLKVFnfFRE400&format=json

I get 0 posts from graph api, I am using the application Token to get the posts from a particular user.